# What are the worse case scenarios if I assign a wrong exception?

Tags: java, exception

Let's say I will catch an ArithmeticException instead of InputMismatchException to handle the input of an integer. If I enter a string, it corrected the exception during runtime to InputMismatchException even though I catch an ArithmeticException.

```
private static int test() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            try {
                return s.nextInt();
            } catch(ArithmeticException e) { // ArithmeticException instead of InputMismatch

            }
       }

}
```

Comment: "[...] it corrected the exception during runtime to InputMismatchException [...]"? There is no chance for an `ArithmeticException` to be thrown, and any `InputMismatchException` will just never be caught.

Comment: This really isn't a good question... "will this cause problem in the future?" Maybe? Your IDE autocorrects to InputMismatchException because that's one of the only three exceptions that Scanner.nextInt() can possibly throw. Read the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have a fundamental misunderstanding about catching exceptions. When you write:

```
} catch(ArithmeticException e) { 

}
```

You are catching the exception, not assigning it. When you get a `InputMismatchException` it is because it is thrown from the `Scanner` class. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html):

> Each catch block is an exception handler that handles the type of exception indicated by its argument. The argument type, ExceptionType, declares the type of exception that the handler can handle and must be the name of a class that inherits from the Throwable class.

Catching an error is a way to handle the error, not assign it.

When you put the wrong exception in the catch block it just means that you will be trying to handle the wrong error, and that the error you are trying to handle will not be handled.